# Why does a semicolon after a for statement cause a compile error?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, runtimeexception

For my Java class, we are asked to add a semicolon to a working for statement and explain why the output is what it is. I don't understand why adding the semicolon creates an erroneous tree type error resulting in the code being unable to compile. Below the code is the output; I have also added backslashes to the any tag because it wasn't displaying otherwise. So, why does a semicolon after a for statement cause such an error? Thanks in advance.

```
package fordemo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input a number:");
            int number = user_input.nextInt();
            for (int n = 1; n <= number; n += 2) ;
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**run:**

```
Input a number:

9

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - 
Erroneous tree type: <\any>\

at fordemo.ForDemo.main(ForDemo.java:35)

Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Actually, it's perfectly legal, it's just not particularly practical...in this case at least

Comment: @MadProgrammer fair point, retracted

Comment: if you wanted something like that, maybe **for(;;);** would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're teminating the `for-loop` with a `;`...`for (int n = 1; n <= number; n += 2);` <--- See `;` here, this means that the loop does nothing and then `n` becomes undefined, is it's defined only within the context of the `for-loop` itself...

Try something more like...

```
for (int n = 1; n <= number; n+=2 ) {
    System.out.print(n + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your code (whitespace changes only) to make it readable.

```
package fordemo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Question 2 */
        {
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input a number:");
            int number = user_input.nextInt();
            for (int n = 1; n <= number; n+=2 );
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem should be apparent now.

`n` is not in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop don't have a body

```
for (int n = 1; n <= number; n+=2 ); // execute and exit and nothing do
```

Then you call `System.out.print(n + " ");`, `n` is not visible here. Since you are call it from outside the scope of that variable

You can use as following

```
for (int n = 1; n <= number; n+=2 ) {
  System.out.print(n + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you terminate `for loop` with `;`, it equavilent to

```
for (int n = 1; n <= number; n+=2 ) {
     //do nothing
}
//here n is out of variable scope
System.out.print(n + " ");}
```

In fact, `for loop` should be

```
for (int n = 1; n <= number; n+=2 ) {
     System.out.print(n + " ");
}
```